# error reading data from the pre-filled database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have a database that lies in assets/databases/.  I use the library [android-sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) Tried to archive the database, did not help. The error all the same gets out

```
   E/SQLiteAssetHelper: Couldn't open databases/brodsky.db for writing (will try read-only):
    com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/databases/brodsky.db file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:336)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:310)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.copyDatabaseFromAssets(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:436)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:400)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:176)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:254)
        at rodionova.lyubov.brodsky.db.PoemsProvider.query(PoemsProvider.java:40)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1140)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:262)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:506)
```

DbHelper:

```
    public class PoemsDbHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static String DB_NAME = "databases/brodsky.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public PoemsDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }
}
```

well and a class ContentProvider as it is also specified in errors in logs

public class PoemsProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private static final UriMatcher URI_MATCHER = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    private static final int POEMS = 1;
    private static final int POEM = 2;
    private static final int FACTS = 3;
    private static final int BIOGRAPHY = 4;

```
static {
    URI_MATCHER.addURI(PoemsContract.AUTHORITY, "poems", POEMS);
    URI_MATCHER.addURI(PoemsContract.AUTHORITY, "poems/#", POEM);
    URI_MATCHER.addURI(PoemsContract.AUTHORITY, "facts", FACTS);
    URI_MATCHER.addURI(PoemsContract.AUTHORITY, "biography", BIOGRAPHY);
}

private PoemsDbHelper poemsDbHelper;

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    poemsDbHelper = new PoemsDbHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection,
                    @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = poemsDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    switch (URI_MATCHER.match(uri)) {
        case POEMS:
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(sortOrder)) {
                sortOrder = PoemsContract.Poems.COLUMN_ID + " DESC";
            }

            return db.query(PoemsContract.Poems.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder);

        case POEM:
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                selection = PoemsContract.Poems._ID + " = ?";
                selectionArgs = new String[]{id};
            } else {
                selection = selection + " AND " + PoemsContract.Poems._ID + " = ?";

                String[] newSelectionArgs = new String[selectionArgs.length + 1];

                System.arraycopy(selectionArgs, 0, newSelectionArgs, 0, selectionArgs.length);

                newSelectionArgs[newSelectionArgs.length - 1] = id;

                selectionArgs = newSelectionArgs;
            }
        case FACTS:
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(sortOrder)) {
                sortOrder = PoemsContract.Facts.COLUMN_ID + " DESC";
            }

            return db.query(PoemsContract.Facts.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder);
        case BIOGRAPHY:
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(sortOrder)) {
                sortOrder = PoemsContract.Biography.COLUMN_ID + " DESC";
            }

            return db.query(PoemsContract.Biography.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder);

        default:
            return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `private static String DB_NAME = "databases/brodsky.db";`

You should use `private static String DB_NAME = "brodsky.db";`

SQliteAssetHelper includes the following in the readme file :-

> Extend SQLiteAssetHelper as you would normally do SQLiteOpenHelper,
>   providing the constructor with a database name and version number:
>
> ```
> public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
>
>     private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "northwind.db";
>     private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
>
>     public MyDatabase(Context context) {
>       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> SQLiteAssetHelper relies upon asset file and folder naming
>   conventions. Your assets folder will either be under your project
>   root, or under src/main if you are using the default gradle project
>   structure. At minimum, you must provide the following:
>
> A databases folder inside assets A SQLite database inside the
>   databases folder whose file name matches the database name you provide
>   in code (including the file extension, if any) For the example above,
>   the project would contain the following:
>
> ```
> assets/databases/northwind.db
> ```